# Image Cropping Tool (Python)

Tags: python, image, tiff, python-imaging-library

I'm a film photographer who deals a lot with cropping/image resizing. Because I shoot film, I have to scan my negatives and crop each frame out of the batch scan. My scanner scans four strips of six images each (24 frames/crops per scan).

A friend of mine wrote me a script for Python that automatically crops images based on inputted coordinates. The script works well but it has problems in the file format of the exported images.

From the scan, each frame should produce a 37mb TIFF at 240 DPI (when I crop and export in Adobe Lightroom). Instead, the Cropper outputs a 13mb 72 DPI TIFF.

Terminal (I'm on Mac) warns me about a "Decompression Bomb" whenever I run the Cropper. My friend is stumped and suggested I ask Stack Overflow.

**I've no Python experience. I can provide the code he wrote and the commands Terminal gives me.**

Thoughts?
This would be greatly appreciated and a huge HUGE timesaver.
THANK YOU!

```
ERROR MESSAGE: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py:2192: DecompressionBombWarning: Image size (208560540 pixels) exceeds limit of 89478485 pixels, could be decompression bomb DOS attack.
```

Answer (score 56):

PIL is merely trying to protect you. It'll not open larger images, as that could be a vector of attack for a malicious user to give you a large image that'll expand to use up all memory. Quoting from the [`PIL.Image.open()` documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open):

> **Warning**: To protect against potential DOS attacks caused by “[decompression bombs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_bomb)” (i.e. malicious files which decompress into a huge amount of data and are designed to crash or cause disruption by using up a lot of memory), Pillow will issue a `DecompressionBombWarning` if the image is over a certain limit.

Since you are not a malicious user and are not accepting images from anyone else, you can simply *disable* the limit:

```
from PIL import Image

Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = None
```

Setting `Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS` disables the check altogether. You can also set it to a (high) integer value; the default is `1024 * 1024 * 1024 // 4 // 3`, nearly 90 million pixels or about a 250MB uncompressed data for a 3-channel image.

Note that for PIL versions up to 4.3.0, by default, all that happens is that a *warning* is issued. You could also disable the warning:

```
import warnings
from PIL import Image

warnings.simplefilter('ignore', Image.DecompressionBombWarning)
```

Inversely, if you want to prevent such images from being loaded altogether, turn the warning into an exception:

```
import warnings
from PIL import Image

warnings.simplefilter('error', Image.DecompressionBombWarning)
```

and you can then expect the `Image.DecompressionBombWarning` object to be raised as an exception whenever you pass an image in that would otherwise demand a lot of memory.

As of [PIL v5.0.0](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releasenotes/5.0.0.html#decompression-bombs-now-raise-exceptions) (released Jan 2018), images that use *twice* the number of pixels as the `MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS` value will result in a `PIL.Image.DecompressionBombError` exception.

Note that these checks also apply to the [`Image.crop()` operation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.crop) (you can create a *larger* image by cropping), and you need to use PIL version [6.2.0 or newer](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releasenotes/6.2.0.html#security) (released in October 2019) if you want to benefit from this protection when working with GIF or ICO files.

Comment: Thank you! That bit about disabling the pixel limit just saved me HOURS of trying to figure out how to deal with it.

Comment: Just to add that as of [ver.5.0, these warnings are upgraded to DecompressionBombErrors for images that are twice the size of images that trigger the DecompressionBombWarning](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/releasenotes/5.0.0.html#decompression-bombs-now-raise-exceptions).

Comment: @buran: thanks for the heads-up! That's an important detail, so I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Pillow docs](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open):

> **Warning:** To protect against potential DOS attacks caused by "[decompression bombs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_bomb)" (i.e. malicious files which decompress into a huge amount of data and are designed to crash or cause disruption by using up a lot of memory), Pillow will issue a `DecompressionBombWarning` if the image is over a certain limit. If desired, the warning can be turned into an error with `warnings.simplefilter('error', Image.DecompressionBombWarning)` or suppressed entirely with `warnings.simplefilter('ignore', Image.DecompressionBombWarning)`. See also [the logging documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html?highlight=logging#integration-with-the-warnings-module) to have warnings output to the logging facility instead of stderr.